# Adding a new field to the bottom of the task descriptor

Tags: c, ubuntu, linux-kernel, task

When we add a new field to the task descriptor (task_struct), why should we add it to the bottom of the task_struct ?

If some entries are expected to be in certain places, which entries are those?

I could not find anything about this on the internet or in the Linux Kernel Development book.

Comment: `why should we add it to the bottom of the task_struct?` - Where have you found this recommendation? As opposite, comment after the last field, `struct thread_struct thread;`, says that nothing should be added after it. Some perfomance issues could arise when someone add new field between fields used in common scenarios. But these issues can be detected mostly with testing.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to tailing of thread structures struct thread_struct,
Please confirm how threads structures are maintained within task struct [may be link list] or may be tailing of these structures